# Analyzing runtime of a short algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, analysis

I got the following code given:

```
public class alg 
{
    public static int hmm (int x)
    {
        if (x == 1)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        return 2*x + hmm(x-1);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(hmm(x));
    }
}
```

So first question is, what does this algorithm count?
I have just typed and runned it in eclipse
so I can see better what it does (it was pseudocode before, I couldn't type it here so I typed the code). I have realized that this algorithm does following: It will take the input and multiply it by its following number.
So as examples:

```
input = 3, output = 12 because 3*4 = 12.  
Or Input = 6, output 42 because 6*7 = 42.
```

Alright, the next question is my problem. I'm asked to analyze the runtime of this algorithm but I have no idea where to start. 
I would say, at the beginning, when we define x, we have already got `time = 1`
The if loop gives `time = 1` too I believe.
Last part, `return 2x + alg(x-1)` should give "something^x" or..? 
So in the end we got something like "something^x" + 2, I doubt thats right : /

edit, managed to type pseudocode too :)

```
Input: Integer x with x > 1
if x = 1 then
  return 2;
end if
return 2x + hmm(x-1);
```

Comment: Since there are no loops, the running time is proportional to the number of recursions. Since there is only a single recursion step `hmm(x-1)` and assuming `x > 0`, the number of recursions is simply `x - 1`.

Comment: Are you sure that the algorithm returns `42` for the input `6`? Doesn't the algorithm return `2^x * x!`?

Comment: @Codor If I'm any judge, it should return `x² + x`. It calculates the double of the arithmetic progression ... via recursion.

Comment: I see, I misread that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have trouble, try to walk through the code with a (small) number.

**What does this calculate?**

Let's take `hmm(3)` as an example:

1. `3 != 1`, so we calculate `2 * 3 + hmm(3-1)`. Down a recursion level.
2. `2 != 1`, so we calculate `2 * 2 + hmm(2-1)`. Down a recursion level.
3. `1 == 1`, so we return `2`. No more recursions, thus `hmm(2-1) == hmm(1) == 2`.
4. Back up one recursion level, we get `2 * 2 + hmm(1) = 2 * 2 + 2 = 4 + 2 = 6`. Thus `hmm(2) = 6`
5. Another level back up, we get `2 * 3 + hmm(2) = 6 + 6 = 12`

If you look closely, the algorithm calculates:

`2*x + ... + 4 + 2`

We can reverse this and factor out `2` and get

`2 * (1 + 2 + ... + x)`.

Which is an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), for which we have a well-known formula (namely `x² + x`)

**How long does it take?**

The asymptotic running time is `O(n)`.

There are no loops, so we only have to count the number of recursions. One might be tempted to count the individual steps of calculation, but those a are constant with every step, so we usually combine them into a constant factor `k`.

**What does `O(n)` mean?**

Well ... we make `x - 1` recursion steps, decreasing `x` by `1` in every step until we reach `x == 1`. From `x = n` to `x = 1` there are `n - 1` such steps. We thus need `k * (n - 1)` operations.

If you think `n` to be very large, `- 1` becomes negligible, so we drop it. We also drop the constant factor, because for large `n`, `O(nk)` and `O(n)` aren't that much different, either.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for this detailed and precise reply, very much appreciated! :) I have understood it! But thanks to everyone else too who replied in my thread :D

Answer (score 0):

The function calculates

```
f(x) = 2(x + x-1 + x-2 + ... + 1)
```

it will run in `O(x)`, i.e. `x` times will be called for constant time `O(1)`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'will be called for constant time `O(1)`'?

Comment: it's means there is constant amount of calculation, not depend on x value.

Comment: It's an example of Big O notation: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/.